# How to enable subscription product in paypal checkout SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to add subscription in paypal checkout and I am using paypal checkout SDK but this not working

```
$environment = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment(PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID, 
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient($environment);

$request = new \PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');

$subscription = ['plan_id' => '23423432',
'start_time' => '2023-09-01T00:00:00Z', 
'quantity' => 1];

$request->body = [
"intent" => "CAPTURE",
"purchase_units" => [[
    "reference_id" => $orderInfo['id'],
    "amount" => [
    "value" => $orderInfo['total'],
    "currency_code" => "AUD"
    ],
    'subscription' => $subscription,
]],
    "application_context" => [
        "cancel_url" => FRONTEND_APP_URL."order-status/?pstatus=payment-declined&source=paypal",
        "return_url" => FRONTEND_APP_URL."order-status/?pstatus=payment-processing&source=paypal"
    ] 
];
```

But in paypal nothing showing related to subscription. Please let me know how i can fix that

Answer (score 1):

#### Better Approach

Hi, in my opinion, you should use the **cURL method** in PHP which might be a better approach.

#### Tools

This is the **cURL-to-PHP converter** that might help ([Get it here](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/))

#### Take Note:

1. Ready your API credential - *client ID* & *secret* ([Get it here](https://developer.paypal.com/home))

#### Sample Project

https://github.com/HongYang01/tmf2234-web-hosting-service/blob/main/vendor/paypal_8_activatePlan.php